# HTML: Select Option input select box Font size not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style an input select box, changing all of the **Font size**. However, when I load the webpage the select box still has the default font size. Any help please?

```css
.shopengine-category-select-wraper select option {
   font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

```html
   <div class="shopengine-category-select-wraper">
      <select class="shopengine-ele-nav-search-select" name="product_cat">
         <option value="">Categories</option>
         <option class="" value="95">Women's </option>
         <option class="" value="93">Men's </option>
         <option class="" value="92">Daniel Wellington </option>
         <option class="" value="88">Master Classic Watch </option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: It is working fine, it has the given font-size!

Comment: input box not working

Comment: Alright! I answered

Answer (score 1):

You should give the size to select only the option font-size inherit from its parent.

```css
.shopengine-category-select-wraper select {
   font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

```html
<div class="shopengine-category-select-wraper">
      <select class="shopengine-ele-nav-search-select" name="product_cat">
         <option value="">Categories</option>
         <option class="" value="95">Women's </option>
         <option class="" value="93">Men's </option>
         <option class="" value="92">Daniel Wellington </option>
         <option class="" value="88">Master Classic Watch </option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add css for both (select, which is the input, and option, which are the options)

```css
.shopengine-category-select-wraper select,
.shopengine-category-select-wraper option {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

```html
<div class="shopengine-category-select-wraper">
  <select class="shopengine-ele-nav-search-select" name="product_cat">
    <option value="">Categories</option>
    <option class="" value="95">Women's </option>
    <option class="" value="93">Men's </option>
    <option class="" value="92">Daniel Wellington </option>
    <option class="" value="88">Master Classic Watch </option>
  </select>
</div>
```